# PHP secure database connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My hosting webserver root is  /public_html, I created a folder in same level as public_html ( /private ) and created a .ini file containing my database login info as I saw in this tutorial

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-do-you-store-your-mysql-user-credentials-in-a-secure-way

so my folder structure look like this

```
 /
  |
  -private
  |   |
  |   -db.ini
  -public_html
      |
      -website files
      -mailer.php
```

I'm using grecaptcha. I want to validate if no bots are using my form, send an email notification to my email and lastly to save customer info to a small database. My grecaptcha is working fine, the email is getting sent  i have a problem getting the info to my database.

```
 <?php
// Checks if form has been submitted
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    function post_captcha($user_response) {
        $fields_string = '';
        $fields = array(
            'secret' => 'USERINFO',
            'response' => $user_response
        );
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

        $result = curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch);

        return json_decode($result, true);
    }

    // Call the function post_captcha
    $res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

    if (!$res['success']) {

          $output = json_encode(array('success' => false));
          die($output);

    } else {

        if($_POST) {
            $to = "admin@tremecji.com"; // your mail here
            $name = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            $phone = filter_var($_POST["phone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $message = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $subject = "$name pregunta desde tremeji.com";
            $body = "Mensaje enviado de pagina tremecji.com\nMENSAJE: $message\nE-MAIL: $email\NUMERO DE CONTACTO: $phone";

            if(@mail($to, $subject, $body)) {

                 //db connection  ==================================================
                 //$mysqli = new mysqli('host','user','password','db');  <--- this used to work 

                $mydb = parse_ini_file('../private/db.ini');
                $mysqli = new mysqli( $mydb['servername'],$mydb['username'], $mydb['password'], $mydb['dbname']);


                // revision de conneccion
                if( $mysqli -> connect_error ){
                    die( 'Connec error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error . ': ' .$mysqli->connect_error );
                }

                 // insert data 
                 $sql = "INSERT INTO clientes (nombre, email, telefono ) VALUES('{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['telefono'])}'";
                $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);


                 $mysqli->close();
                 $output = json_encode(array('success' => true));
                 die($output);
             }
         }

    }
}
```

It used to work before I tried to secure my login info, i have tried changing the path to my db.ini file with no success

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing YOLO operator (`@`) obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances. You should display an error message for the user, log a problem, initiate some kind of retry, or all of these things in conjunction.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Are there any warnings being printed?

Comment: what is `$mydb` then? is the `parse_ini_file` failing or do you get values there? How does this ini file look like? What does `$mysqli->connect_error` say? Did you check for `myqli::error` after the insert query?

Comment: @tadman Thanks! I'm new to PHP this script is a result of multiple examples i put together. I check out the info you provided me

Comment: If you're new to PHP that's great, but be aware that a lot of the material floating around out there in the form of "tutorials" is very out of date, PHP has been around a long time and practices have changed significantly since it was introduced. [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com) is a good resource to help guide your learning.

Comment: @Jeff my .ini file looks like this   
`[database]
servername = localhost
username = admin
password = password
dbname = db_main`
I have never worked with PHP i still don't know how to check debugs. i will check in to this Thanks!

Comment: do a `var_dump($mydb);`  right after the parse_ini_file line to see what you got there.

Comment: @tadman I've checked in to parameterized queries and it did make things more simple to see

Comment: @tadman thanks for that . I've also debugged my code and notice that the login info from the .ini file was correct. i finally ended up changing my connections variable name to plain c  and everything worked. I don't know if it was the parameterized queries or the variable name change that worked for me but thanks for pointing me to those articles